# Silverlight and .NET RIA Services - Managing Users

Tags: silverlight

I am building a Silverlight 3 application that uses .NET RIA Services. This application is hosted in an ASP.NET application that uses the default aspnet_Membership tables. My Silverlight application requires users to login. If they are a member of a certain role, I want to allow them to manage the application's users.

Currently, I can authenticate a user and see what roles they belong to. However, I cannot figure out how to do other tasks handled by the ASP.NET [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx). Things like creating users, resetting their password, etc.

How do I do these types of things through a Silverlight application that uses .NET RIA Services?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but as I checked MembershipProvider, there are already methods for [`Creating Users`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx), [`Resetting Password`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx), [`Changing Passwords`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.changepassword.aspx) or [`Deleting Users`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.deleteuser.aspx)

Or probably you wanted to ask something else or probably the question is incomplete?

Comment: Aww! I get it. This class defines the contract. The million dollar question is why don't they use an Interface in this case?

Comment: The MembershipProvider does have these methods. The problem is, they are not exposed through RIA Services. How do I expose these methods through RIA Services?

Comment: You are working on the client which consumes the service. The problem is now actually on the server side since they are not implemented or exposed.